# Set marker icon url from variable

Tags: javascript, icons, google-maps-markers

I would like to change the marker's icon dynamically based on the result of an  IF statement.

When the value of markers[i][0] equals red, it should use the url for the red marker icon. In case of blue, the blue icon should be used.

```
var markers = [ ['abc','123','456','red'],['def','124','556','blue'] ];

for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
   var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
   bounds.extend(position);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: position,
     map: map,
     title: markers[i][0],

     if( markers[i][1] = 'red') {
     var jel = '{url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png"}';
     }
     else {
     var sign = '{url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"}';
     }
     icon: sign
   });
}
```

Consolse says:

```
" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ " 
at the line (11) where I write  "markers[i][1] = 'red')"
```

.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Upps I see a small miswritting at line 12. It should be : "var sign" instead of "var jel".

Answer (score 0):

```
var markers = [ ['abc','123','456','red'],['def','124','556','blue'] ];

for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
   var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
   bounds.extend(position);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: position,
     map: map,
     title: markers[i][0],
     icon: markers[i][3] === 'red'
      ? '{url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png"}'
      : '{url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"}'
   });
}
```

Comment: Not good. It gives the same error: " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ "